# React Native stand alone app showing expo icon before my first screen is shown

Tags: react-native, expo

I just detached my RN apps since I need to use native lib. Then, I tried to generate my APK from Android Studio. However, after installing to my phone, my apps shows expo icon (similar with expo building javascript bundle...) before it redirects to my first screen. It did not happen before I detaching my RN project.

[image: Expo img]

It shows that picture for few secs, before go to my first screen. Is it an issue or I need to do something after I detached my project?

(Expo ver: 23.0.4)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Expo is opensource , they don't force to that , You can set your own icon in app.json , see here :

https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/guides/configuration.html